# Sorted results in function tojson

Tags: android-json

`Gson.tojson(object)` returns a alphabetically sorted json-string.

How can I keep the original sort order (from the database)?

Comment: Could you give us a more specific example of what you are doing and what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i am reading a json object using 
jsonstring = gson.tojson(jsonobject) via urlconnection.

jsonobject is like {"fieldZ: "name", "fieldA: "name2",....}

when i am using toast to display the string (android-app) the result displayes is in alphabetical order of the json-fields.

I would like to display same order as if connect via url.